# JOLT Remove based on value and keep rest of the json keys

Tags: java, arrays, json, dataframe, jolt

Below is my JSON and i need JOLT to remove if destSiteName is unknown. Need to keep the rest of the object.

```json
{
  "destSiteName": "unknown",
  "customer_code": "code1"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a **shift** transformation which contains two conditionals

- whether outermost attribute is **`"destSiteName"`** or not ( **`"*"`** )

or

- whether value of **`"destSiteName"`** is **`"unknown"`** or not ( **`"*"`** )

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "destSiteName": {
        "unknown": "",
        "*": { "@1": "&2" }
      },
      "*": "&"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

```json
{
  "operation": "shift",
  "spec": {
    "destSiteName": {
      "unknown": null,
      "*": "&"
    },
    "*": "&"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "destSiteName": ""
   }
 }
```

Comment: Hi. This answer seems to be untested, indeed it's wrong currently